# I want to extract data from the Data Frame based on first letters of column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame like this:

```
     Flt Desg Eff Date Dis Date       day of week                 Routing
0    AI  0922    8-May    8-May        ....fri,..          riyadh-calicut
1    AI  0381    8-May   12-May     .tue,..fri,..         singapore-delhi
2    AI  1242    8-May   13-May  .tue,wed,.fri,..          dhaka-srinagar
3    AI  0130    9-May    9-May        .....sat,.           london-mumbai
4    AI  0174    9-May    9-May        .....sat,.    san francisco-mumbai
..        ...      ...      ...               ...                     ...
615  AI  1932   25-Jul   25-Jul        .....sat,.            jeddah-delhi
616  AI  1936   25-Jul   25-Jul        .....sat,.         borispill-delhi
617  AI  1938   25-Jul   25-Jul        .....sat,.    manas-srinagar-delhi
618  AI  1942   25-Jul   25-Jul        .....sat,.        dammam-bengaluru
619  AI  1954   25-Jul   25-Jul        .....sat,.  doha-mumbai-vijayawada

[620 rows x 5 columns]
```

I want to extract the data of Flt, Desg, Eff Date, Dis Date , day of week based on Routing which starts from `moscow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
cols = ['Flt', 'Desg', 'Eff Date', 'Dis Date', 'day of week']
df1 = df.loc[df['Routing'].str.startswith('moscow'), cols]
```

If need all columns:

```
df2 = df[df['Routing'].str.startswith('moscow')]
```